# Realloc struct array as a function parameter yields segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, realloc

I have searched quite a bit, before asking, but I can't seem to make this function work. 
I have this `array of structs` with 2 strings (char*)
 and the function `put()` that adds a new struct,
 Unless the key already exists in that case it just ovewrites the current value with the new one.

Despite I am passing the array by *reference* and *not making a local copy* in the function, the memory still is corrupted `(Segmentation Fault)`.

The source code is compiled under **Ubuntu 15.10** on latest version of **gcc**.

 Thanks in advance for your help guys!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 3

struct store{
    char *key;
    char *value;
};

void put(char *key, char *value, struct store **store, int size){
    int i, found;
    struct store *temp = realloc(*store, (size + 1) * sizeof(struct store));
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(strcmp(key, store[i]->key) == 0){ //Key found, overwrite new value.
            store[i]->value = strdup(value); //Assume that every value is null terminated
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) return;

    *store = temp;
    if(!store){ 
         perror("realloc failed");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }    
    store[size]->key = strdup(key); //New element
    store[size]->value = strdup(value);
    return;
}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    struct store *store = malloc(N * sizeof(struct store));
    if(!store){ 
       perror("malloc failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    store[0].key = strdup("123a");
    store[1].key = strdup("456b");
    store[2].key = strdup("789c");
    store[0].value = strdup("John");
    store[1].value = strdup("Sam");
    store[2].value = strdup("Mary");

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        printf("%s, %s\n\n",store[i].key,store[i].value); //This works fine

    put("123a","Jim",&store,N);
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        printf("%s, %s\n\n",store[i].key,store[i].value);

    put("653a","Tom",&store,N);
    for(i = 0; i < N+1; ++i)
        printf("%s, %s\n\n",store[i].key,store[i].value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct store *temp = realloc(*store, (size + 1) * sizeof(struct store));
for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    if(strcmp(key, store[i]->key) == 0){ //Key found, overwrite new value.
        store[i]->value = strdup(value); //Assume that every value is null terminated
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(found) return;

*store = temp;
```

If the key is found, you don't assign `temp` to `*store`. `realloc` can move the allocated memory to a completely new address, thus leaving `*store` a dangling pointer. And you really should also check that `temp` isn't null as well.

There's also the problem of your misuse of `store`. `store` is the the address of the pointer you passed into the function, not the first element of an array.

You need to index the array like this `(*store)[i]`.

Comment: @wing - No. Because `realloc` will return NULL on failure, but won't free what you passed to it. So the memory will leak if you assign directly. You need the intermediate pointer.

Comment: @wing - It's correct syntax-wise, it's just not always happening. And you most certainly shouldn't free before realloc. That will make your program have undefined behavior. Just check that temp isn't NULL, and if it isn't assign it to `*store`. Move the line that calls `realloc` *after* the loop.

Comment: @wing - See my edit. And please rollback your own edit. It makes answers wrong when you incorporate fixes they propose into your question code.

Comment: @wing - Yes. Right now your loop treats `store` as an array of pointers, which it isn't.

Comment: @wing - Yes that would be it.

Comment: @wing - Did you update all uses of `store[i]` to `(*store)[i]` inside `put`?

Comment: @wing - Please also observe that this `put("653a","Tom",&store,N);` is wrong. You need to send the current size instead of N, otherwise the array won't grow.

Comment: @wing - It's a good idea to modify `put` so it will return the new size instead of guessing. As for why you still get another segmentation fault. I really cannot say. You should do [some debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)